# What's the equivalent of the item function in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

`polars` `select()` returns a df with the shape: `(1,1)`. How do I get just the item in this shape?

```py
df.filter(myCondition).select('columnName')
```

What's the polars `.item()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Polars 0.26.0 and before:

- use `pl.first` as shown in the other answer
- use the indexing `df.filter(myCondition).select('columnName')[0,0]`

Both are a bit ugly in case you know, and want to verify, that your output is a scalar, and hence `.item()` has been added in the latest master. See https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/5893. So this should land in the next release, probably 0.26.1.